# Как убрать GET параметр из URL или сделать его ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

Есть ссылка `сайт.ру/?uid=123`, нужно `сайт.ру/uid123`

В файл **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

добавил строку:

```
RewriteRule ^uid([\d+]+)$ /?uid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Все работает и страница по ссылке: `сайт.ру/uid123` открывается.

**Вопрос:** другую ссылку `сайт.ру/edit?uid=123` тоже нужно сделать в вид: `сайт.ру/edit/uid123`. Добавил в .htaccess строку:

```
RewriteRule ^edit/uid([\d+]+)$ /edit/?uid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Но она не передает $_GET['uid'] параметр (пустой приходит). Помогите настроить регулярку!

Answer (score 1):

Решение моего вопроса:

```
RewriteRule ^editprofil/uid([0-9]+)$ /editprofil?uid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^uid([\d+]+)$ index.php/?uid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```